# Git: push remote A branch Foo to remote B branch bar

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

Is it possible to push `A/foo` to `B/bar` where `A` and `B` are remotes( different, obviously ), and `foo` and `bar` are branch names?

Comment: Yes, you just do it. It's not clear what you've tried and what problems you encountered. If you had just tried it, it would have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply pull it first to a temporary local branch, then push it to the remote:

```
git checkout -b tmp
git pull A foo
git push B tmp:bar
```